# Undefined "this" in Angular factory

Tags: angularjs, undefined, factory

I have am Angular Factory that creates global on screen alerts, but unsetting the alerts errors with an 
**"TypeError: undefined is not a function"** error.

My Factory is:

```
 'use strict';
angular.module('meanstackStarterApp')
  .factory('Alerts', function ($timeout) {

    var alertType = null;
    var alertTitle = null;
    var alertMessage = null;

    return {
        setMessage: function(type, title, message, timed) {
            console.log("in");
            this.alertType = type;
            this.alertTitle = title;
            this.alertMessage = message;
            if (type == "alert-danger")
            {
                alertMessage = message + alertMessages.alertMessage_GlobalTryAgain;
            }
            if (timed)
            {
                // Set Timeout on unset
                $timeout(this.unsetMessage(),5000);
            }
        },

        unsetMessage: function() {
            console.log("out");
            this.alertType = null;
            this.alertTitle = null;
            this.alertMessage = null;           
        }
    };
  });
```

The `setMessage` function works fine but the `unsetMessage` errors on the `this`.

If I remove `this` prefix from the variables, the code runs through without erroring, but does not actually set the factory variables.

What am I missing?

Comment: this.unsetMessage(this) --- Why you are passing this here?

Comment: `this` in `unsetmessage` refers to `unsetmessage` and `this` in `setmessage` refers to `setmessage`

Comment: @PraveenPrasannan That was a previous in carnation when I was trying to solve it...edited now.

Comment: @NaeemShaikh How come the setMessage sets the factory variables?

Comment: it does not! it creates its own variables within the `setmessage` function. if you want try to call `setmessage` with `timed=true`, you will get the error for `function unsetmessage undefined` inside `setmessage`

Comment: @NaeemShaikh But the controller that references it and uses the values in this factory gets updated values from it.

Comment: Ben, this will always refer to the function in which it is used. your accepted answer shows it.

Comment: @NaeemShaikh  I agree, I'm just trying to figure out how the setMessage function manages to do the job, if it's not setting the service wide variables.  Curious and confusing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have here something like you, I'm changing your code to look like mine:

```
angular.module('meanstackStarterApp')
  .factory('Alerts', function ($timeout) {
    var self = this;

    var alertType = null;
    var alertTitle = null;
    var alertMessage = null;


    self.setMessage = function(type, title, message, timed) {
            console.log("in");
            self.alertType = type;
            self.alertTitle = title;
            self.alertMessage = message;
            if (type == "alert-danger")
            {
                alertMessage = message + alertMessages.alertMessage_GlobalTryAgain;
            }
            if (timed)
            {
                // Set Timeout on unset
                $timeout(self.unsetMessage(this),5000);
            }
        };

     self.unsetMessage = function() {
            console.log("out");
            self.alertType = null;
            self.alertTitle = null;
            self.alertMessage = null;           
        };

     return self;
  });
```